# Sitecore Web Api 404 page not found?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-status-code-404, sitecore

I am using the Sitecore Web Api to access my Content tree from a non Sitecore web application, but when I try the request I get an 404 file not found error. I have tripled check the GIUD, so that is not the problem.

The settings in the web.config and sitecore.ItemWebApi.config

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="....|/-/item/v1/|...."/>

<site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">true</patch:attribute>
</site>
```

The HttpWebRequest

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid={5E219167-DCC0-4C28-A123-064CACCCCE69}");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Are you able to access the endpoint through a rest client such as Fiddler or Postman?

Comment: I have not tired. I am pretty new to sitecore, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I used PostMan and I still get the 404

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: 7.1. The ItemWebApi is version 1

Comment: So are you getting an IIS 404 or a Sitecore 404 message?

Comment: Sitecore 404 Erroe message

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try:

- Make sure the guid is correct and there are no restrictions on it from sitecore client
- Make sure the item is published unless you are running in Live mode
- Try accessing the REST endpoint through PostMan
- Try accessing the Home item's REST endpoint through PostMan
- Check sitecore logs for any errors

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. First of all my host name didn't resolve directly to a site in IIS, secondly the dll was corrupted.